# Combine scenes: render do not combine

Tags: compositing-nodes

I try to combine two scenes with the compositing nodes interface.
The first scene is some meshes in a dark-blue background and the second is a text in a transparent background.

I combine them with these nodes and the backdrop viewer show the good combining that I want:
[image]

But when I do a true render image it show me the render of the first scene and the second scene separately:

[image]

It renders the first scene and seconds later the render become the second scene and stop like this (like in the .gif in the description). I want them overlap each other. The second scene upper.   The scene with text and transparent background has the render transparent box checked.

Comment: Are you saying that it renders both, but they should be overlapping?

Comment: In your Alpha Over node like you have (mix) factor =1.0 instead of 0.5.

Comment: They render both in a weird way. It render the first scene and 3 seconds later the render become the second scene and stop like this (like in the .gif in the description). Yes I want them overlap each other. The second scene upper.

Comment: It not change with the factor 0.5. And the backdrop work correctly with factor 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup works fine for me. Here cube and plane are in different scenes. Make sure to go after rendering to scene where you actually compose (I assume its default Scene) and choose Render Result in image viewer.
**Edit: looks like you are using compositing in two scenes at the same time, so compositing from second scene immideately overrides first scene after rendering. Leave compositing only in one desired scene (I think just deleting all nodes should work).**

[image]

Comment: In viewer node it work. But in render result it show me only the first scene.

Comment: check edit please

Comment: I deleted the nodes in second scene. But still the same result.